# Speech to text on emulator

Tags: android, emulation, voice

I am developing an app that converts speech to text, however, it appears that the 
Emulator doesn't have a microphone feature from what I researched on the forums.

I have android phone, and can run it on the phone phone.

But is there any way to get speech from the telephone, and run application on emulator, because I want to develop my app on higher api than my phone.

Comment: Sorry for my grammer. I want to get speech from my android device and run my speech to text application on emulator.As i researh there is not an option to activate microphone of emulator.

Comment: @MichaelGardner that was an invalid edit. The OP didn't say anything about using a recorded file, just about using a microphone in general. I've rolled back your edit, and fixed the post myself.

Comment: @Richard - He mentioned getting speech from the phone, so I made the assumption...probably a leap to far on my part.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect answer, but there is a great community out there for flashing ROMs on to your phone, and putting a newer version of android onto it. One of the most common ones is [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org), and I would suggest seeing if there is a ROM available for your specific phone model.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little involved but you could try writing a socket server that would run on the emulator while creating a socket client that runs on the physical phone. The phone would capture the audio and send it via socket stream to the server which would make it available to your app via an interface. The hidden benefit here would be that your app would bind to an interface rather than a concrete class which would make altering the source of the incoming audio more flexible. The socket server may sound like a lot but it's not too difficult, I've written such a socket server for desktop to device communication and it feels difficult until you realize how to properly read/close your streams.